# Why people play cards during Ugadhi?

Tags: belief, culture, festivals

Is there any significance of doing gambling on this Ugadhi day? I am seeing from my childhood days, people keep playing cards all over the city without any fear of cops during these day. Any myth behind this?

Comment: Where? Looks like cultural question.

Comment: Cant specify the city name. Especially happening, if you roam outside, you will come to know about this...

Comment: what do you mean by "if you roam outside, you will come to know "?. Gambling has nothing to do with Ugadi. This is not related to Hinduism.

Comment: I am curious to know is there any relationship of this gambling on this auspicious day "Ugadhi". Roam outside means, dont mistake. May be in your city or where you are put up, you may not see. But if you come out of that place this day and observe you will see many people gambling today

Comment: I think the answer may simply be that police don't want to arrest people during holiday time, it may not have any connection with Hinduism as such.

Comment: Never heard of such a practice. Gambling during Deepavali is common in North India. Never during Ugadi.

Comment: @moonstar - Ill come with you then, what's special in deepawali then?

Comment: @Mithun  No religious relation between gambling and Deepavali either. A cultural misdoing is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relation between Ugādi and gambling cards. In fact thee is no relation with gambling with any Hindu festival. This is just a custom which became popular. Spending quality time with friends and family might be a reason behind this. This is just like people drinking bhaang(a fermented drink) on Holi. This does not scriptural basis for this neither.

Ugadi is the new year in many states where lunar calendar is followed. The following are to be done on Ugadi festival.

- Taking oil bath (abhyaṃgana snānaṃ) before sun rise.
- Wearing new clothes because it is the new year. It signifies a new beginning in our life.
- Respecting our parents has always been a part in our culture. Bowing down to parents. Then praying lord for his blessings in the new year.
- Eating [Ugadi paccaḍi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugadi#Practices)<sup>1</sup> and other special dishes. Niṃba kusuma bhakṣaṇaṃ meaning Eating neem flowers is important on Ugadi. This indicates that you should be ready to face bitter experiences in your life too.
- Inviting friends and family to our home(if possible) and listening to early prediction. This is called as paṃcāṃga śravaṇaṃ. These predictions help in planning our life in the coming new year.
- Then listening to stories of lord in the evening. Spending most of the time in listening to the stories of lord till the night.

Source - [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHg7JTNvujI)(Telugu)

<sup>1.Some people add salt and pepper(or chilly) in Ugādi  paccadi. Our festivals are always linked with health. Ugadi paccadi also has importance in health also. Adding salt and pepper nullifies raw mango which helps in keeping blood pressure in normal levels. Adding anything and everything in some dishes according to our own wish is not recommended.</sup>